# Running a project in svn repository

Tags: java, svn

I just wonder when developing a big java project we always use a svn repository for code sharing but is it possible to run the project in that repository?

Or is there any system for java that allows more than one user to develop and test same project in one place?

Comment: I strongly advise you to consider reading SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html

Comment: I know that but I'm trying to explain that the source files already there aren't they. So I'm wondering is there a way to compile/build and run the project from my IDE which is already connected to that svn for code sharing purposes. I hope that this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository only stores your code you cannot run the code from the repository.

If you want to build/test the code centrally then you need a Continuous Integration Server (CI) like Jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/)

This server can extract the project from svn build it, run the tests (if any) and even deploy it on a server.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about it the wrong way - when a developer works on a project they download what's called a "working copy" of that repository, then run it and make changes / test it on their local computer. When they're done, they then "commit" the changes to the repository, where they become available to everyone else.

You don't run the project in the repository directly.

Comment: Thanks, I know that but the thing I want to do is let's say I have VPS that I use for repository and I want to be able to run that project in repository as if it is running from that vps. To be more clear I want to trigger this execution process from let's say Eclipse because I know the project is already exists there.

Comment: @FDem I'm not entirely sure what you mean - but presumably you could check out a working copy on your VPS and then run it from there? Or is this a server application?

Comment: More realistic example then: I have server at ip address : 1.1.1.1 which holds my svn repository thus holds my source codes and project infos etc. Then there is me and my team working in an office with ip addresses 2.2.2.1-5. We are connected to that repository (1.1.1.1) for checkout, commit etc. Is it possible to build & run that source codes in 1.1.1.1 from our computers from 2.2.2.1? In theory there source codes are there so why not?

Comment: @FDem There's a difference between a repository and a working copy, you can't build directly from the repository even on the server that holds it - you can "check out" a working copy (or several working copies, one for each user) on that server if you want to. You could also use something like Jenkins to always produce an up-to-date build, if that's what you're after?

Comment: Yes I needed to hear that I can't do what I want:) Thank you for your answers. Now I'm checking this Jenkins thing.

Answer (score 0):

In major IDE's such as Eclipse, Jdeveloper, Netbeans, there is build in functionality for version control.

So you use your ide to build your app or make changes to it, and using update/commit functionality of the versioning  system you have the desired outcome.